# Can a wired (ethernet) Mac act as a WiFi access point?

Tags: wifi, airport

A MacPro '10 running 10.6.8, connected to the network via Ethernet.

If I'd like to add a [webcam](http://foscam.us/products.html?gclid=CJme_7zf5sMCFVA8gQodKzgALQ) is a router required or can I set up direct access? i.e. can AirPort act as an access point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. When Ethernet is connected, go to Sharing System  Preference Pane. You can share the Internet there by selecting Ethernet as a source.